# Magento - Backslash in the file path causing issue with CSS / JS files

Tags: magento, firefox, backslash

My file-path contains forwardslashes  and backslashes, example:

http://test.com/magento/media/css\skin\kwazy\css\styles_1_cp.css

This works fine on i.e / safari / chrome, however Firefox interprets the backslash to be %5c and the links are broken:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWbxl.png

I'm hoping that there is a solution to this problem. I think I need to change the backslashes to forward slashes, however I've looked around for information and don't know how to.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP url spec uses forward slash (/) as the delimiter.

Some browsers might at their discretion, attempt to correct a path string (what comes after 'http://www.example.com/') but it's not something you should try to depend on as you've found.

The cure is to follow proper syntax and correct your website.

**Afternote:** Issue with backslashes in URL string was being caused by a third party Module called Diglin UI Optimization which consolidates and compresses CSS and Javascript. **After contacting Diglin**, they recommend going to GitHub and downloading their latest version from here to fix the issue:

https://github.com/diglin/Diglin_UIOptimization

Comment: I would love to enter proper syntax, however I don't know how to do this. My JS / CSS files are being read from the windows path. The forwardslashes become backslashes only after I compress the files. using an extension called Diglin UI Optimization. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to contact the extension developer and find out why their extension is failing. It should not be doing that. You mention Windows, is that your live server or a development server? You'll need to tell them under what environment the issue is occurring. BTW, FireFox tends to follow RFCs and W3C standards and demands the code it's fed do so as well. It was in reaction to Internet Explorer's do your own thing that was causing us such issues...

Comment: Diglin has a new version available to fix the backslash issue.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1210/24064 has solution for specific to windows and works well with one of theme forest's purchased theme.(not found anything in their support queue too)